# Pass Canvas as a Graphics 2D object android

Tags: java, android, canvas, graphics2d

I'm very new to developing on Android so I apologize if this is an ignorant question. I have some existing java code that allows a user to pass a Graphics2D object to a particular shape object into the render method on that shape to draw it on the graphics object. Like so:

```
public void render(Graphics graphics, int deltaX, int deltaY) {
    move(center, deltaX, deltaY); //Shape Attributes/methods
    graphics.drawRect((int) center.getX(), (int) center.getY(), (int) width, (int) height);
}
```

I'm looking into using this code in an Android app. However I'm finding that the easiest way to do this in Android is using Canvas.

My question is this: Is there a way to adapt a canvas object to a graphics2d object, or does the existing code need to be modified to accept a canvas object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I guesss `Graphics` used in your codes is `java.awt.Graphics`, if so, you won't use it because it contains native code, so unless someone ports that native code to Android.

Android has its own [graphics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary) package, you could use these class to achieve your object.

plz ref [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawRect(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)), here is [an example](https://alvinalexander.com/android/how-to-draw-rectangle-in-android-view-ondraw-canvas)

Comment: Could you give an example? Are you saying that I would need to change my code to use the android graphics package?